# Problem with Subscript indices in Matlab - after one rotation of the for loop

Tags: matlab

I have a problem with my code in Matlab, which is pretty strange. 
I have a for loop which contains a couple of statements about some dates, here is the code:

```
for i=1:data_length_Added

  if (month(dateAdded(i)) ~= 0) && (month(dueDate(i)) ~= 0) && (month(dueDate(i)) == month(datePublished(i)))
        [~,idx]=ismember(month(dueDate(i)),kpit(:,1),'rows');% finds the position of an element from the array in the array for months
        kpit(idx,2) =kpit(idx,2) + overdue(i);
        kpit(idx,3) = kpit(idx,3) + 1;
        idx = idx + 1;
  else
        if (month(dateAdded(i)) ~= 0) && (month(datePublished(i)) == (month(dueDate(i)) + 1)) && month(dueDate(i)) ~= 0
              [~,idx]=ismember(month(dueDate(i)),kpit(:,1),'rows');
              [~,idx1]=ismember(month(datePublished(i)),kpit(:,1),'rows');
              year1 = year(datePublished(i));
              weight = (day(datePublished(i)))/eomday(year1,month(datePublished(i)));
              kpit(idx,2) =kpit(idx,2) + overdue(i);
              kpit(idx1,2) =kpit(idx1,2) + overdue(i)*weight;
              kpit(idx,3) = kpit(idx,3)+ 1;
              kpit(idx1,3) = kpit(idx1,3)+ 1;
        else
              if (month(dateAdded(i)) ~= 0) && (month(datePublished(i)) ~= 0) && (month(datePublished(i)) > (month(dueDate(i))+1)) && (month(dueDate(i)) ~= 0)

                    [~,idx]=ismember(month(datePublished(i)),kpit(:,1),'rows');
                    year1 = year(datePublished(i));
                    weight = day(datePublished(i))/eomday(year1,month(datePublished(i))); %Should count all overdue days for full months and weighted overdue days for not full months
                    kpit(idx,2) = overdue(i)*weight;
                    kpit(idx,3) = kpit(idx,3) + 1;

                    for j=month(dueDate(i)) : (month(datePublished(i))-1)
                          [~,idx]=ismember(month(dueDate(i)),kpit(:,1),'rows');
                          kpit(idx,2) =kpit(idx,2) + overdue(i);
                          kpit(idx,3) = kpit(idx,3)+ 1;
                          j = j + 1;
                          month(dueDate(i)) = month(dueDate(i)) + 1;
                    end

              else
                    if (month(dateAdded(i)) ~= 0) && month(dueDate(i)) ~= 0 && month(datePublished(i)) == 0
                          [~,idx]=ismember(month(today),kpit(:,1),'rows');
                          year1 = year(today);
                          weight = day(today)/eomday(year1,month(today)); %Should count all overdue days for full months and weighted overdue dats for not full months
                          kpit(idx,2) = overdue(i)*weight;
                          kpit(idx,3) = kpit(idx,3) + 1;
                          for j=month(dueDate(i)) : (month(today)-1)
                                [~,idx]=ismember(month(dueDate(i)),kpit(:,1),'rows');
                                kpit(idx,2) =kpit(idx,2) + overdue(i);
                                kpit(idx,3) = kpit(idx,3)+ 1;
                                j = j + 1;
                                month(dueDate(i)) = month(dueDate(i)) + 1;
                          end
                    end
              end
        end

  end
end
```

So, the problem is that I run the code successfully through the loop and the problem occurs after the first date I have on line 367(before that I have only zeroes). Basically, I have no problems with the zeros before the first date that actually gets into the first nested loop and the first date, the problem occurs after that. What do you think that could possibly cause the problem with the subscript indices error I receive?
Thanks :)))

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZeUB.png)

Comment: Insufficient information for anybody to help as we don't know what your data is like or even where the error occurs in this code! Use the debugging tools, look at which variables cause the problems and their sizes at that point. https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html

Comment: I am sorry about that, but I thought it will be too much. I have four different vectors which form a matrix. On some rows I have dates but on other I don't - I have zeros in stead. I am using the debugging tool that's how I understood at which line I have the problem. I am attaching a picture in the question for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to resolve my problem. I had to change the way I call the dates which are empty in my if statements. Firstly I had set zeros for the empty dates but after that  I changed them to NaN, so I can check when I have NaN what action to do. 
This is the working code:

```
mDateAdd = month(dateAdded);
mDatePubl = month(datePublished);
mDueDate = month(dueDate);
mToday = month(today);

         dateAdded(dateAdded == 0) = NaN;
        datePublished(datePublished == 0) = NaN;
        dueDate(dateAdded == 0) = NaN;


     for i=1:data_length_Added
          if mDueDate(i) == mDatePubl(i) && ~isnan(dateAdded(i)) && ~isnan(dueDate(i))
                [~,idx]=ismember(mDueDate(i),kpit(:,1),'rows');% finds the position of an element from the array in the array for months
                kpit(idx,2) =kpit(idx,2) + overdue(i);
                kpit(idx,3) = kpit(idx,3) + 1;
                idx = idx + 1;
          else
                if ~isnan(dateAdded(i)) && (mDatePubl(i)) == (mDueDate(i) + 1) && ~isnan(dueDate(i))
                      [~,idx]=ismember(mDueDate(i),kpit(:,1),'rows');
                      [~,idx1]=ismember(mDatePubl(i),kpit(:,1),'rows');
                      year1 = year(datePublished(i));
                      weight = round((day(datePublished(i)))/eomday(year1,mDatePubl(i)));
                      kpit(idx,2) =kpit(idx,2) + overdue(i);
                      kpit(idx1,2) =kpit(idx1,2) + overdue(i)*weight;
                      kpit(idx,3) = kpit(idx,3)+ 1;
                      kpit(idx1,3) = kpit(idx1,3)+ 1;
                else
                      if ~isnan(dateAdded(i)) && ~isnan(datePublished(i)) && mDatePubl(i) > mDueDate(i)+1 && ~isnan(dueDate(i))

                            [~,idx]=ismember(mDatePubl(i),kpit(:,1),'rows');
                            year1 = year(datePublished(i));
                            weight = (day(datePublished(i))/eomday(year1,mDatePubl(i))); %Should count all overdue days for full months and weighted overdue days for not full months
                            kpit(idx,2) = kpit(idx,2) + round(overdue(i)*weight);
                            kpit(idx,3) = kpit(idx,3) + 1;

                            for j = mDueDate(i) : (mDatePubl(i)-1)
                                  [~,idx]=ismember(mDueDate(i),kpit(:,1),'rows');
                                  kpit(idx,2) =kpit(idx,2) + overdue(i);
                                  kpit(idx,3) = kpit(idx,3)+ 1;
                                  j = j + 1;
                                  mDueDate(i) = mDueDate(i) + 1;
                            end

                      else
                            if ~isnan(dateAdded(i)) && ~isnan(dueDate(i)) && isnan(datePublished(i))
                                  [~,idx]=ismember(mToday,kpit(:,1),'rows');
                                  year1 = year(today);
                                  weight = round(day(today)/eomday(year1,mToday)); %Should count all overdue days for full months and weighted overdue dats for not full months
                                  kpit(idx,2) = overdue(i)*weight;
                                  kpit(idx,3) = kpit(idx,3) + 1;
                                  for j=mDueDate(i) : (mToday-1)
                                        [~,idx]=ismember(mDueDate(i),kpit(:,1),'rows');
                                        kpit(idx,2) =kpit(idx,2) + overdue(i);
                                        kpit(idx,3) = kpit(idx,3)+ 1;
                                        j = j + 1;
                                        mDueDate(i) = mDueDate(i) + 1;
                                  end
                            end
                      end
                end

          end
    end
```